# Adding short codes from a page's content on header and hiding the same from page's content

Tags: shortcode, templates, content

I have created a page and added the following shortcode from wp-orbit-slider

```
 [orbit-slider category="test"]
```

I want the contents of

```
 [orbit-slider category="test"]
```

be displayed on the header part, instead of on the content area part, which the wordpress usually does . I tried adding the the short code on header.php and it works, but the same content will be duplicated on the content area also. I need to avoid this. How can this be achieved ?

Comment: Add shortcode to `header.php` and remove it from your page.

Comment: My page.php displays contents by  <?php the_content(); ?> function. So how can this be done, also I need to restrict only shortcodes of  [orbit-slider] only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you, trying to hook early to `the_content` filter to strip the shortcode tag from it:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'ad_filter_the_content',1,1);
function ad_filter_the_content($content) {
    // specify page id or array of page ids to include
    if (is_page(5)) {
        return str_replace('[orbit-slider category="test"]', '', $content);
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this piece of code was the most suited for my requirement

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP call for a Shortcode. It works like this:

```
echo do_shortcode('[orbit-slider category="test"]');
```

But I think, from your question, that you may have different Shortcodes for each page. If this is the case, try adding a Custom Field for your Pages, containing the `category` for your Orbit-Slider.

Of course, if you use the build in Taxonomy System (e.g. the standard Categories) you do not have to use a Custom Field, you can just use the Category. I use the first Caategory for the Categoryversion - be sure to handle the exceptions yourself here.

```
// for the custom field version
$orbitcategory = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'my_orbit_slider', true );
// for the Taxonomy version
$orbitcategory = get_the_category( get_the_ID() );
$orbitcategory = $orbitcategory[0]->name;



$thisslider = '[orbit-slider category="' . $orbitcategory . '"]';

echo do_shortcode( $thisslider );
```

You should be fine like this.

And remember to not put your shortcode into the Content again :)

Comment: My requirement was that I needed to add short code on content, but that shortcode should not appear on content, instead it should appear on the header part.

Comment: Okay, didn't get it the first time. But a custom metabox would be the userfriendlier Version than inserting the Shortcode into the content an dnot displaying it there.

Comment: Thanks for that information,any good url for creation of custom metabox?

Comment: I would start at the [Codex Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box), gives you a great overview and starting point for future Questions :)